# Jquery mobile loader widget content disappers on show

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-loader

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.1 and phone gap for my project. I have encountered the problem on the Android device that whenever i am displaying the loader widget in jquery mobile the content in the background disappears. I want it to look like an overlay but currently its loading into the page. And once the request is completed the content displays again.

For showing the loader I am using

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
```

**EDIT:**
Got this to work.

I was handling the following property in css which was creating the issue.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: This question is useless without an example. Your problem is probably related to your own project because this is not a common behavior of this component.

Comment: Accepted. But is there anything i need to keep a check of while calling this loader on the page.

Comment: From your question I would assume you have manually modified AJAX loader widget?

Comment: I have got the catch will edit it here itself.

Comment: @CodemasterGabriel add ur solution as an answer

Comment: I have already provided that as an edit in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got the solution to this,

In case this particular css is added to the app it will hide the backface data.
So I removed the line from the CSS file

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

and it worked like a charm.